# Specifying Future[Done] as materialized value when creating a source

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'm trying to write some code as part of a larger integration test.

I have a function that creates a `KinesisSource` of type `Source[KinesisRecord, Future[Done]`:

```
protected def createKinesisSource(config: KinesisClientLibConfiguration): Source[KinesisRecord, Future[Done]]#Repr[MyFile.KinesisFlow] = {
  KinesisSource(config).mapAsync(1)(processRecord)
}

protected def processRecord(record: KinesisRecord): Future[KinesisFlow] = {
    Future { validateRecord(record) }
}
```

I want to create a fake source of the same type from a file. I have (pardon the code, I'm new to scala):

```
val records = scala.io.Source.fromFile("testFile.txt").getLines.toList
  .map(i => {
    new KinesisRecord( ByteString.fromString(i), "x", None, "x", None, Instant.now(), "x")
  })

Source(records).mapAsync(1)(processRecord)
```

That gives me a `Source[KinesisRecord, NotUsed]`. How can I change that to `Source[KinesisRecord, Future[Done]]`? I understand that the second parameter is the materialized value ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46499925/whats-the-use-and-meaning-of-second-type-parameter-in-akka-source)), but I'm not sure how to specify that value without actually applying a `run` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `mapMaterializedValue(_ => Future.successful(Done))` or `Future.never`

But if the materialized value has impact in your integration tests this will affect them because the Future will complete right after stream materialization or never.